# Erro de declaração na class phpmailerException

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

Eu utilizo o wordpress, e estou utilizando o plugin `contact form 7`.
Ao enviar um e-mail clicando no botão, ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class phpmailerException, because the name
>   is already in use in
>   /home/storage/d/94/6a/renovedigital/public_html/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php
>   on line 4040

Indo até essa linha encontrei o seguinte código:

```
4025 /**
4026  * PHPMailer exception handler
4027  * @package PHPMailer
4028  */
4029 class phpmailerException extends Exception
4030 {
4031     /**
4032      * Prettify error message output
4033      * @return string
4034      */
4035     public function errorMessage()
4036     {
4037         $errorMsg = '<strong>' . $this->getMessage() . "</strong><br />\n";
4038         return $errorMsg;
4039     }
4040 }
```

Comment: Ele está reclamando que essa classe já está declarada e não pode redeclarar. Você está redeclarando essa classe em algum lugar do seu código?

Comment: Se estiver usando `include` troque por `include_once`.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, resolvido!